# Django Rest API vs pure Django

Tags: django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I want to build an app that will use a database.
I already build few of them, with models, views, urls... But I discovered that I can build my own API using Django Rest and use this API in my Django project. So if I undersand I will have to separate apps: -an API and my Django app and all my models and database related datas will be in my API app.
If I want to use vue.js for the frontend in my Django app, using an API will make eveything simpler to implement?

Comment: Yes. You will create some API endpoints like /api/users and then you can call this url with eg. axios like axios.get('/api/users')

Comment: why would you create different app for your `API` and separate `django-apps`?